# str.format() en Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, formato

¿Alguien puede decirme por qué al utilizar `str.format()` en Python es necesario hacerlo dentro de la misma línea donde está declarado el `String`?

Con eso me refiero a que parece no funcionar una vez que el `String` ya tiene contenido.

Aquí un ejemplo que funciona:

```
name="Edgar"
message = "My name is {name}".format(name = name)
print(message)
```

Y uno que no:

```
name="Edgar"
message = "My name is {name}"
message.format(name = name)
print(message)
```

Comment: En tu seegundo ejemplo `message.format(name=name)` funciona correctamente **y te devuelve el resultado**, que no estás guardando. La cadena original (`message`) no resulta modificada nunca, porque es inmutable. Por tanto deberías haber hecho `formateada = message.format(name=name)` y después `print(formateada)`

Answer (score 3):

es debido a que String.format() es una función que devuelve la cadena formateada, por lo que es necesario asignar su resultado a una variable o bien utilizarla directamente.

En el primer caso:

```
message = "My name is {name}".format(name = name)
```

estás asignado el resutlado de la función "format" a la variable message.

En el segundo:

```
message.format(name = name)
```

no estás asignado su resultado a ninguna variable ni queda registrado en ningún sitio, por lo que al hacer

```
print(message)
```

lo haces sobre la variable original y no a la "formateada"

Answer (score 1):

Si quieres almacenarlo en alguna variable puedes hacerlo de tres formas

### 1. Usando `.format()`

De la forma que tu lo estás haciendo, lo único que estás haciendolo de forma incorrecta que no guardas el resultado en una variable.

Lo correcto es dejar el string sin declarar y aplicarle format después, tu ejemplo quedaría así:

```
name="Edgar"
message = "My name is {}"
message = message.format(name)
print(message)
```

**Salida:** `'My name is Edgar'`

### 2. Utilizando el operador módulo %

Así era como se formateaba antiguamete strings en Python, usando tu ejemplo se haría así:

```
name="Edgar"
message = "My name is %s"
print(message % name)
```

**Salida**: `My name is Edgar`

Esta forma de hacerlo aunque es posible no está recomendada por Python como se puede ver en su [documentación](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=sprintf#printf-style-string-formatting):

> The formatting operations described here exhibit a variety of quirks that lead to a number of common errors (such as failing to display tuples and dictionaries correctly). Using the newer formatted string literals or the str.format() interface helps avoid these errors. These alternatives also provide more powerful, flexible and extensible approaches to formatting text.

### 3. Usando la STL

La librería estandar de Python `string` tiene una clase llamada `Template` que puede ser usada para realizar este tipo de sustituciones.

```
from string import Template
message = Template('My name is $name')
message.substitute(name=name)
```

**Salida:** `'My name is Edgar'`

### Conclusiones y bonus extra

Yo siempre usaría `.format()` ya que es lo más conocido por todo los programadores (lo que hará tu código más legible) y lo recomendado por Python.

Tan solo usaría `Template` en el caso de que estes creando un programa en el que usuarios externos vayan a introducir información a ese string. Ya que el método `.format()` es muy poderoso y puede realizar operaciones y cálculos. Esto te puede llevar a resultados no deseados si el input es proporcionado por un usuario. Imaginemos el siguiente Ejemplo:

```
#Quiero ingresar a un usuario que no es el mio
clave = "XyZt"
print("Introduzca su clave:")
message = "{}"

#Me piden que introduzca una clave, como el método format es muy poderoso, ejecuta estas operaciones que me dan la clave sin yo saberla
clave_introducida = message.format(globals()['clave'])

if clave == clave_introducida:
    print("Ha accedido con éxito a su cuenta")
else:
    print("Clave incorrecta")
```

**Salida:** `'Ha accedido con éxito a su cuenta'`

Como podemos ver `.format()` en este ejemplo, *
**en vez de poner literalmente lo que ha ingresado el usuario, realiza las operaciones**, y dicho usuario es capaz de hackear nuestro sistema. Esto no pasaría con `Template` al ser un método menos potente y no realizar dichas operaciones:

```
clave = "XyZt"
print("Introduzca su clave:")
message = Template('%clave')
clave_introducida = message.substitute(clave=globals()['clave'])

if clave == clave_introducida:
    print("Ha accedido con éxito a su cuenta")
else:
    print("Clave incorrecta")
```

**Salida:** `"Clave incorrecta"`